# Misalignment align text in the center

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem align text in the center in the header because of arrow for back page. My code is like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
        <center>
            Domótica
        </center>
    </ion-title> 
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

But the text "Domótica" is not in the center. Somebody know who can resolve it?
Thank in advace.

Best regards.

Comment: Why use the `<center>` tags? Doesn't `ion-title` default to center?

Comment: And I see your question about changing the header line's color didnt work? ;)

Comment: Hahahaha you're right Ivaro18! Still I don't know how to change color of the fuc***ing line :D 
I tasted with "ion-title" but doesn't work...  In Google Chrome work fine but in my smartphone Android doesn't work so... that is the reason for try with <center> and the same problem :S I'm new working with Ionic and a lot of problems.

Comment: And thanks for reply me :)

Comment: The answer Hoang Nguyen gave you should help you with this problem, but seems like Ionic's team agreed that iOS has their title centered, Android does not (check the phone styles: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/)

Comment: nice haha, I'm new to Ionic too! Just trying to learn from other people's problems by trying to fix em hahah

Comment: becase Ionic release too many version and have too many issues for specifix problem in that version. So you should don't care anything, just focus solve problem and learning. =))

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late for this answer but I found a solution to get the back button working using centered title.

You can add this piece of code to your app and it is fixed.

```
.back-button.show-back-button {
z-index: 9999;
display: inline-block;
}
```

It basically move the Z position of the button to the top because by using position: absolute for the title it takes the whole space overriding all elements.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks. if using the above solution for centering, this gets the back-button working again. through various tests, it seems setting padding-right on the logo to center it kept the back button working. about 44px (accounting for the back button width) worked well. but i am going with this for now with the assurance of it being centered exactly.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I am currently using this hack without any problems. I am looking for another solution. Sadly I can't make a pull request about this since android by default is not centered aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use sass to apply customer css . You have to locate sample code in your test.scss in same location with html page

```
ion-title {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0 90px 1px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
```

}

Cheer !

Comment: More explanation about this particular scss file: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-navbar-ion-title-align-center-for-android/52263

Comment: Thanks for reply me, but sorry, I haven't understood very well. I have a folder with my 3 files, (example.html, example.scss, example.ts) so... You say that including your code in my example.scss it should work fine?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've applied that solution for my problem. I am sure it working fine! =))

Comment: Thanks Hoang! It work fine :) now my texts are align in the center but my problem is that only add this code in my scss:

ion-title {
   text-align: center;
}

I can't press back button for change page (only in my smartphone Android, in Google Chrome work fine) Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Ionic 2 didn't handle fix back button hardware. I am looking for solution for this.

Comment: Thank you very much Hoang, I have lost a lot of time trying solve it but I couldn't, so if you get to fix the problem tell me the solution please

Comment: Sure ! =)) @Technico

Comment: @Tecnico For hardware back button. can you try use [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/) and use registerBackButtonAction() method. Cheer !